# c# convert array of the bytes from big to little endian floats

Tags: converters, endianness

I need to do converting from big to little endian in c#.
I've an array of bytes (byte[]) received through UDP. 
How to convert the big endian's byte[] to little endian's float and then print it?
Show me the way, please.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
byte[] data = GetFromUDPInBigEndian();
Array.Reverse(data); // now is in little endian
```